# Angular 2 how to pass an object to the childs

Tags: angular, parent

i'm trying to figure out how to pass an object to it's childs in Angular 2.
For an user page i got the parent which loads the user data from an API.
And 1 child for displaying the data and the other child for displaying the data in a form.

[image]

Now i've tried this in the parent:

```
<h4>{{ userData.full_name }}</h4>
<nav>...</nav>
<user-details [userData]="data"></user-details>
<user-edit [userData]="data"></user-edit>
```

But this results me in showing the parent plus both childs underneath each other instead of only showing when opening the right url (users/:id/details or /edit)

Comment: Please show your routing configuration.

Comment: From the picture you are showing, I assume that <nav> is supposed to be the parent and <user-details> and <user-edit> the children, but on your html the three of then are on the same level.

Comment: My routing config: 
{ path: 'users/:id', component: UserComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: ViewUserComponent },
      { path: 'edit', component: EditUserComponent },
     ]},

Comment: yes @BogdanC that's true

Comment: If that's the case and your data is in <nav> component, you cannot bind like you show the data to the other components.

Comment: My data is in the parent and uses an userService, maybe i can pass data with the service?